# Get the id of the clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I'd like to get the id of the clicked link with jQuery.** Why does this return `Undefined` instead?

```js
test = function(e) {
    alert($(e).attr('id'));
    return false;
}
$('.bleu').click(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="bleu" id="h12">azeaze12</a>
<a href="" class="bleu" id="h13">azeaze13</a>
<a href="" class="bleu" id="h14">azeaze14</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` it refers to the clicked dom element, first parameter in click event handler is `event` object

```js
test = function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
}
$('.bleu').click(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="bleu" id="h12">azeaze12</a>
<a href="" class="bleu" id="h13">azeaze13</a>
<a href="" class="bleu" id="h14">azeaze14</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

replace `e` with `this`, e refers to [event object](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

or even better

```
$('.bleu').click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`, and use [`.prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) for id or simply `this.id`:

```
test = function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
    return false;
}
$('.bleu').click(test);
```

Alternative if the context is bound on the function, eg while binding events on Backbone views, you can use `event.currentTarget`, consider this:

```
$(el).click(function(event) {
  console.log(this) // { "my": "context" }
  console.log(event.currentTarget); // [DOMElement]
}.bind({
  my: 'context'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use click event and use attr to get id. Try this:

```
$(".bleu").click(function(e) { 
  alert($(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User this keyword

```
 <script>
 test = function(e) {
 debugger;
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
     return false;
    }
    $('.bleu').click(test)

  </script>
```